# Configure power control in notification pane

Tags: battery-life

I just bought an Alcatel One Touch 995 with Gingerbread 2.3, when I display the notification the notification pane I have some icons I can click to activate GPS, wifi, bluetooth, rotation...
I know there are some power control tools but I'd like to know if there is a way to cutomize the icons already displayed in my notification pane?

Answer (score 2):

Not by default. Certain ROMs like CyanogenMod do allow you to customise the toggles and the order in which they're displayed.

A possible workaround could be this app - [Notification Toggle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.notificationToggle)

Answer (score 1):

Stock ROMs often don't allow to customize notification toggles. Either you'll have to flash a custom ROM (e.g. CyanogenMod) or install a third-party app (e.g. Widgetsoid).

Answer (score 0):

Not on a stock rom, sorry.

On certain custom/aftermarket ROM's, such as [CyanogenMod](http://cyanogenmod.com), have the ability to customize these icons, by letting you add, remove and reorder the icons.